# Hover and color with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make the menu and bell icons to become red when the relevant menu is visible, so i did an hover function, and a css function, but it seems to be that the hover is overwriting the css rule.

here is the code:

```
// JavaScript Document
var toggleclicks = 0;
var menuclicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.icon-bell').hover(
         function() {
             $('.icon-bell').css({'color': 'red'});
         },
         function() {
            $('.icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'}); 
         }
         );
         $('.icon-menu').hover(
         function() {
             $('.icon-menu').css({'color': 'red'});
         },
         function() {
            $('.icon-menu').css({'color': '#ABABAB'}); 
         }
         );
//WRAPPER//
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
      ++toggleclicks;
      if (toggleclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '0'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': 'red'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         menuclicks = 0;
      }
    });

//NAV BAR//
    $('.toggle-menu').click(function() {
      ++menuclicks;  
      if (menuclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '0'});
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         $('.main-nav').css({'width': '50%'});
         $('.icon-bell').css({'color': '#ABABAB'});
         $('.wrapper').css({'margin-top': '-260px'});
         $('.contact, .diet, .hours, .classes, .gym').css({'margin-bottom': '-300px'});
         toggleclicks = 0;
      }
    });
```

as you can see, it suppose to change the icon color to red when it's odd clicks and the menu opens (with css rule), but it won't happen (the color change).
You can see the live example here: http://boazkerengil.com

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Why are you changing color via js, when you can use .icon-bell:hover in css?

Comment: the :hover in css is being overwritten with the color rules in JS.. and gives the same effect. I want the icon to become red as long as the menu is opened (odd clicks), can't achieve that with CSS.. I think.

Comment: As I see every thing works normally, Can you tell me what is your browser?

Comment: I'm using chrome (latest version), but as i mentioned - the Hover works fine, i want the color of the icon to be red when the .icon-bell/.icon-menu is clicked and while the menu is opened (odd clicks). When im not hovering it returns to grey, even when the menu is opened, and regardless the css rule that changes it to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a class to your menu icon when it is open and assign red color to this class. Some thing like this:

```
.menu-opened {
    color: red;
}
```

Add above class to your menu icon when it is going to be opened. You can do this by jQuery API `addClass` and remove this class when the menu is closing

**EDIT :**

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
      ++toggleclicks;
      if (toggleclicks%2 === 0) {
         // even clicks
         // Other stuff...
         $('.icon-menu, .icon-bell').addClass('menu-opened');
      } else {
         // odd clicks
         // Other stuff...
         $('.icon-menu').removeClass('menu-opened');
         menuclicks = 0;
      }
    });
```

And add this CSS

```
.icon-menu:hover, .icon-menu.menu-opened {
    color: red;
}
```

And **remove** all hover related functions in JavaScript

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it now, and still the same - the Hover works, but it won't keep the red color when i remove my mouse from the icon, even though the menu is opened.

Comment: @BoazKG Never say does not work. You MUST force programming language to work for you. This is the **ART** of programming. I will add a code snippet to my answer

Comment: Works now! i used your advice and used addClass and removeClass, with the CSS :hover, instead of JS hover. thanks.